# How do I access the watchOS 10 double tap and other accessibility gestures

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchkit, watchos

I would like to trigger parts of my app with the watchOS 10 double tap or other accessibility gestures that were introduced in older watchOS versions.

I tried to use the normal SwiftUI gesture recognition or the `WKGestureRecognizer` but both don't seem to support the wanted double tap with the fingers.

Comment: I don’t think it is out yet

Comment: What about the AssistiveTouch gestures? They came out in 2021..

Comment: The double tap is from this year it may be included there but I don’t think it is available yet, check the release notes for Beta Xcode

Comment: Are you talking about the "Assistive Touch"? "Pinch, clench, double pinch, double clench"? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212760

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of those. Let's say I have two buttons and I want to control one with the pinch and one with clench. Would that be possible?